# Convert 2d string array into ArrayList in android

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

How to convert **`2d string array`** into **`ArrayList`**??
I have a 2d array of string, how can i covert it to array list???

Comment: depends on how you want to concat them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a full list of elements just do this. Probably there is a simple way

```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i=0; i < array_limit ; i++)
       for (int j=0 ; j < array_limit; j++)
              list.add(your_array[i][j]);
```

Comment: then how can i relate array itmes?? like how can I find array[2][1]??

Comment: @user1756754 if your array is x*y then array[2][1]=list.get((y*2)+1)........ that is for any i and j array[i][j]=list.get((y*i)+j)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<String> rowsToString(String[][] data) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        String row = Arrays.toString(data[i]);
        list.add( row.substring(1, row.length()-1) );
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you want. Try:

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){

        newList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        newList.get(i).add(a[i][j]);
        }

    }
```

Then you can access elements for example by:

```
newList.get(1).get(2);
```